# Отличаются библиотеки в ide и в терминале

Tags: python, консоль, pycharm, ide, lib

Всем привет, столкнулся с не приятной проблемой. [image]

Я заметил эту проблему при упаковки py в exe при помощи pyinstaller. При полной упаковке выдает ошибку `no module named` , хотя все библиотеки установлены корректно. И с проекта запускается "как надо".

Помогите пожалуйста, как исправить эту проблему ?

Comment: Возможно, в системе установлено несколько питонов. В консоли наберите: `where python.exe`. Сравните с путем, который используется в IDE. Возможно, используется виртуальное окружение.

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо вам большое !